# Blood Bowl pre-match training

Tags: blood-bowl

I have tried ten times or more but every attempt to special train a player in the pre-match phase fails.

What am I doing wrong? How do I increase the chance of success in pre-match training?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You click the button to start the training and you have to click it again to stop it before it reaches the other side.  The closer it gets without actually touching the end mark, the higher your odds of getting a bonus ability point is.

Comment: Lol, now I understand why my trainings always failed. Thanks!